# How to update password encrypted using MD5 and stored into sql server 2005 database

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created a user account table. There are two fields in it Login which stores user id and Password which stores password in encrypted format. The password is encrypted at the time of registration using MD5 hashing. If the user wants to change his password, how will he change it into the database. I tried to update the password using simple update statement, but it didnt work.

My code is:

```
//Code

public int Changep(string strLogin, string strPassword, string newpass)
    {
        //Create a connection
        string cs = "data source=DELL-PC;initial catalog=project;user id=sa;password=pass";
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(cs);


        // Create a command object for the query
        string strSQL = "UPDATE tblLogins SET Password= @Password WHERE Login=@Username AND Password = @Password2";

        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn);

        //Create parameters
        SqlParameter paramUsername;
        paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
        paramUsername.Value = strLogin;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);

        //Encrypt the password
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashedBytes;
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        hashedBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strPassword));
        SqlParameter paramPwd;
        paramPwd = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.Binary, 16);
        paramPwd.Value = hashedBytes;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(paramPwd);

        //Encrypt the old password
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher2 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashedBytes2;
        UTF8Encoding encoder2 = new UTF8Encoding();
        hashedBytes2 = md5Hasher2.ComputeHash(encoder2.GetBytes(strPassword));
        SqlParameter paramPwd2;
        paramPwd2 = new SqlParameter("@Password2", SqlDbType.Binary, 16);
        paramPwd2.Value = hashedBytes;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(paramPwd2);
        int iResults;
        //Insert the record into the database
        try
        {
            objConn.Open();
            //We use execute scalar, since we only need one cell
            iResults = Convert.ToInt32(objCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if(iResults==1)
                return PassUpdated;
            else
                return Updatefailed;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Updatefailed;
        }
        finally
        {
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please reply me soon. I need it urgently

Comment: what's not working?what is the error you're getting?

Comment: What didn't work?  What error(s) are you getting?  What is your table definition?

Answer (score 0):

You're hashing `strPassword` as both the old and new password. I'm thinking you need to prompt for both the old and new password, then hash the old password into your `WHERE` clause.